# Python passing through argsparse argument without stripping quotes

Tags: python

I have a python function that has an arg `-vw`

`-vw` contains single quotes in a json array but they are getting stripped.

I am calling the function like this:

```
python script_name.py -vw '{"path": ["$.TYPE[@VERSION='A.12'].name1"]}'
```

and then printing the -vw field straight away:

```
{"path": ["$.TYPE[@VERSION=A.12].name1"]}
```

In the python script, the args for -vw is set up like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-vw','--name_removed',type=str)
```

Everything else is working as expected but the single quotes around A.12 are being removed.

So far, I've tried passing through with `''A.12''` and `'''A.12'''` but neither have worked.

Is there a solution?

Comment: You're trying to nest single-quotes. That's not going to work.

Comment: try escaping them around A.12 (\'A.12\'), what's probably happening is that the single quotes close and begin new around A.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I solved it a minute later!

Passing through the below seems to work:

```
python script_name.py -vw '{"path": ["$.TYPE[@VERSION='"'A.12'"'].name1"]}'
```